# Bash array export workaround

Tags: arrays, bash, export

We know that exporting arrays in a canonical way is impossible, but I am interested in finding a workaround. I have a following scenario: a list of variables is loaded from a file to an array during startup, and I need to have that array visible to several bash scripts that may or may not be executed in the parent environment (`. example.sh` or just `example.sh`). I tried many things, but something like this seems as most promising:

```
export j=1
export array$j=something
```

And then I tried to access the value using:

```
echo ${array[$j]}      #doesn't work in child script
echo $(echo \$array$j) #displays the actual '$array1' instead of 'something'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up values through indirection using parameter expansion:

```
j=1
array1=something

name="array$j"
echo "The value of $name is ${!name}"
```